# Vertical align text with multiple rows in a CSS circle

Tags: html, css

I've created a circle that contains a text, and the text needs to always be centered. Simple enough, and I've found a lot of examples of this with words on one row using `line-height` for example.

My problem is that the text will sometimes contain one row, sometimes two and sometimes three and I can't get that to work.

Any ideas?

**[I've created a fiddle here with three examples.](http://jsfiddle.net/tdtx3cfe/)**

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="splash">Lorem</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="splash">Lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="splash">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container{
    position: relative;
    width: 70px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.splash {
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
    background: green;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    transform: rotate(15deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(15deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(15deg);
}
```

Comment: Why do you need `position:absolute` on you `.splash` class? If you remove it, it will work just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see this http://jsfiddle.net/tdtx3cfe/2/, I got it working with a little different approach, inserting the text into the span and making it `display:table-cell`, `vertical-align:middle`, change the splash to `display:table`, this will work even if you want to keep splash absolute

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="splash"><span>Lorem<span></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="splash"><span>Lorem ipsum<span></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="splash"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor<span></div>
</div>


.container{
    position: relative;
    width: 70px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.splash {
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
    background: green;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: table;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    transform: rotate(15deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(15deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(15deg);
}
span{
    display:table-cell;
     vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create an extra span tag inside `.splash` and center it via position absolute and transform translate trick

```
.container{
    position: relative;
    width: 70px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.splash {
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
    background: green;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    transform: rotate(15deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(15deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(15deg);
}

.splash span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

For a markup like this :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="splash"><span>Lorem</span></div>
</div>
```

An example: http://jsfiddle.net/tdtx3cfe/3/

Comment: Improved example (cleared `border-radius` and made percent height/width): http://jsfiddle.net/tdtx3cfe/7/

Answer (score 0):

As one of the options, you can align splash with [flexible boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes):

```
.container {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    display: inline-flex;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: green;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.splash {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    transform: rotate(15deg);
}
body {
    display: flex
}
```

I had to add `body` style to vertically align containers.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tdtx3cfe/6/).